# Test an app created in django 1.4 for compatibility with django 1.7

Tags: compatibility, django-1.4, django-1.7

I have an existing application developed in django 1.4. I want it to upgrade to django 1.7.
I can make the changes if some modules are deprecated since i don't need the backward compatibility. For this i need more information on which part of my application needs to be modified. So a testing tool that scans my application, and tells what needs to modified would be much better.

Is there any tools as such? If so, please guide me through it.

Thanks.

----Edit----
There is no such software available :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read thru the release notes and change your code if necessary.

```
{% url viewname %}
```

in 1.4 has become since 1.5

```
{% url 'viewname' %}
```

And no need for south application since its built in now since 1.7

And "commit_on_success()" has become "atomic()" since 1.5 i think.

I dont think, there is a tool which upgrades your code for you. I would say, just upgrade your django, run your lokal page and fix all deprecation/old-code errors.. this is how i find out what has been changed ;)

Comment: Or is there any tools like 2to3 in python?

Comment: @sengottuvel no, there isnot.